# 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable when trying to annotate a hash variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, annotations

The following `dataclass`:

```
from abc import ABC
from collections.abc import Mapping
from dataclasses import dataclass, field

@dataclass(eq=True, order=True, frozen=True)
class Expression(Node, ABC):
    def node(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

is used as a base class for:

```
@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True)
class HashLiteral(Expression):
    pairs: Mapping[Expression, Expression]
    ...
```

`Node` is defined as:

```
@dataclass(eq=True, frozen=True)
class Node:
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        raise NotImplementedError
```

When trying to use the `HashLiteral` class I get the error:

```
pairs: Mapping[Expression, Expression]
TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

What is wrong with my annotation of `pairs` above?

Comment: Can you add the `fields` to the `Expression` example? Is `Node` a `dataclass`?

Comment: @wwii my bad, updated the example to be more complete!

Comment: Do you define `Mapping`, or are you using `typing.Mapping`?

Comment: @PatrickHaugh I in fact got it from `collections.abc`

Comment: Use the one from `typing` instead. The `collections.abc` version doesn't know about type hinting.

Comment: Can you add that as an answer?

Comment: add `from __future__ import annotations` to top of the file

Comment: I had the same problem and the last comment from @erandac solved the issue! Thanks

Answer (score 77, accepted):

You should use `typing.Mapping` instead of `collections.abc.Mapping`.  `typing` contains many generic versions of various types, which are designed to be used in type hints.  According to the [`mypy` documentation](https://mypy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/builtin_types.html), there are some differences between the `typing` classes and the `collections.abc` classes, but they're unclear on exactly what those differences are.

Comment: Looks like this was changed in version 3.9 of Python so that you can now import from collections.abc  [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/typing.html#type-aliases)

Comment: @Golden Lion: `from typing import Mapping`.