# TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable on Callable

Tags: python, type-hinting, mypy

I have an issue with the way python 3.8 and mypy work together. Consider this code:

```
from collections.abc import Callable

def feeder(get_next_item: Callable[[], str]) -> str:
    return get_next_item()
```

While mypy approves this code, running it using python 3.8 creates an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypytest.py", line 3, in <module>
    def feeder(get_next_item: Callable[[], str]) -> str:
TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

So, Lets try something else:
from collections.abc import Callable

```
def feeder(get_next_item: Callable) -> str:
    return get_next_item()
```

At this point, python3.8 will run it fine, but mypy will say

```
mypytest.py:4: error: Returning Any from function declared to return "str"
```

Is there any way out of this trap, except using #type: ignore on the return?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you seen this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955751/abcmeta-object-is-not-subscriptable-when-trying-to-annotate-a-hash-variable)?

Comment: To be honest, I saw it, but I didn't think it was relevant to me, as it was talking about mapping, not callable. I'll get back to you if this solves my problem soon

Comment: Yes, it solved it. So just for the record, I'll post a code that works as an answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable when trying to annotate a hash variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955751/abcmeta-object-is-not-subscriptable-when-trying-to-annotate-a-hash-variable)

Answer (score 6):

Thanks XtianP. Just for the record, this code worked well for me

```
from typing import Callable

def feeder(get_next_item: Callable[[], str]) -> str:
    return get_next_item()

print( feeder(lambda : 'Hi man') )
```