# TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable when running PageRank of PySpark

Tags: python, pyspark, iterable, typing, abc

I'm trying to run [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/pagerank.py) implementation of Page Rank. This is a part of the code:

```py
import re
import sys
from operator import add
from typing import Iterable, Tuple

from pyspark.resultiterable import ResultIterable
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


def computeContribs(urls: ResultIterable[str], rank: float) -> Iterable[Tuple[str, float]]:
    """Calculates URL contributions to the rank of other URLs."""
    num_urls = len(urls)
    for url in urls:
        yield (url, rank / num_urls)


def parseNeighbors(urls: str) -> Tuple[str, str]:
    """Parses a urls pair string into urls pair."""
    parts = re.split(r'\s+', urls)
    return parts[0], parts[1]
```

But when I run it, I get this error:

```
10 from collections.abc import Mapping
     11 
---> 12 def computeContribs(urls: ResultIterable[str], rank: float) -> Iterable[Tuple[str, float]]:
     13     """Calculates URL contributions to the rank of other URLs."""
     14     num_urls = len(urls)

TypeError: 'ABCMeta' object is not subscriptable
```

What should I do? I have no idea why should I define types when defining functions.

Comment: A little late but this may be similar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59955751/abcmeta-object-is-not-subscriptable-when-trying-to-annotate-a-hash-variable)?